# i'm trying to use firebase push notification React Native cli

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qA2q.png)i'm trying to use firebase push notification when i try to get the token nothing shows in the console and get that error: Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

that's my code :

```
  // firebase.initializeApp();
  // async function requestUserPermission() {
  //   const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  //   const enabled =
  //     authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
  //     authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  //   if (enabled) {
  //     console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  //   } else {
  //     console.log('Authorization status');
  //   }
  // }
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   requestUserPermission();
  // }, []);
  // messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  //   console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  // });
  // firebase.initializeApp();
  // var db = firebase.firestore();
  // const {userInfo, introSlider} = useContext(AuthContext);

  // const checkToken = async () => {
  //   const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  //   if (fcmToken) {
  //     console.log(fcmToken);
  //   } else {
  //     console.log('Failed to get');
  //   }
  // };
  // checkToken();
  // await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  // const token = await messaging().getToken();
  // async function onMessageReceived(message) {
  //   // Do something
  // }
  // messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
  // messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);


  useEffect(()=>   async function onAppBootstrap() {
    // Register the device with FCM
    await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  
    // Get the token
    const token = await messaging().getToken();
  
    // Save the token
    console.log('/users/1234/tokens', { token });
  }, [])
```

ive tryed amost everything in android file